# Data Structure in array NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, nullpointerexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NullPointerException when Creating an array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922677/nullpointerexception-when-creating-an-array-of-object)

I am having NullPointerException in main method, in line

```
array[0].name = "blue";
```

Structure Class:

```
public class Items {

String name = "";
String disc = "";
}
```

Main Class :

```
public class ItemsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Items[] array = new Items[2];

            array[0].name = "blue"; //NullPointerException
        array[0].disc = "make";
        array[1].name = "blue";
        array[1].disc = "blue";
           }
}
```

Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067286/java-nullpointerexception-in-array

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145728/nullpointerexception-being-thrown-whenever-array-member-is-accessed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Items[] array = new Items[2];
```

You have to initialize each element of array, by default they are `null`

Make it,

```
Items[] array = new Items[2];
//initialization
array[0] = new Items();
array[0].name = "blue"; //NullPointerException
array[0].disc = "make";

//initialization
array[1] = new Items();
array[1].name = "blue";
array[1].disc = "blue";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote the line:

```
Items[] array = new Items[2];
```

You initialized an Array of the type Items which can contain 2 elements, or in other words, you only initialized the container.

Each element in the array is an object and also needs initialization, and when addressing `array[0].name` you're trying to access the inner element which is currently `null`
If you'll check Jigar Joshi [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11538754/1510122), you'll see he also initializes each Items element inside the array.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
Items[] array = new Items[2]; // Creates an array of Items with null values
```

Hence have to use

```
Items[] array = { new Items(), new Items() }; // as suggested by aioobe....
```

or need to intialise the array like

```
array[0] = new Items();
```