# Arrays: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

what I've done wrong? I think it's cause the array. The line numbers are incorrect now, because I had to short my text a little bit, sorry for that.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Team.<init>(Team.java:43)
    at Team.main(Team.java:30)
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Dein Fußballteam in der ersten Bundesliga!");

    int[] Spieler = new int[20];
    int Torschützen[] = new int[10];  

    Team myTeam = new Team();
    myTeam.einfacheNachricht();
}

public Team() 
{
    TeamSpieler = new Spieler[20];
    Scanner team = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0; i<20;i++){
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie den Namen des Spielers " + i + " ein: ");
        TeamSpieler[i].Name = team.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie das Alter des Spielers " + i + " ein: ");
        TeamSpieler[i].Alter = team.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie die Tore des Spielers " + i + " ein: ");
        TeamSpieler[i].Tore = team.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Bitte geben Sie den Namen ihres Teams ein: ");
    Teamname = team.nextLine();
              team.close();
}
```

Comment: One, post your exception.  Two, remove unnecessary code.  Three, make it clear what line the exception refers to.  Four, explain why you think that line should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - NullPointerException in Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067286/java-nullpointerexception-in-array)

Answer (score 5):

This row:

```
TeamSpieler = new Spieler[20];
```

doesn't create `20` new `Spieler`s, it only creates `20` `Spieler` references, initialized to `null`.

To avoid `NullPointerException`s, you need to do

```
TeamSpieler[i] = new Spieler();
```

for each `i`.

Also, please follow `Java` coding standards, variable names should start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: It seems as if there are Problems betweeen the line  
Team myTeam = new Team();
and  
TeamSpieler = new Spieler[20];

Comment: @L3V0: Yes, that row calls the constructor of `Team`, which in turn tries to initialize all the `Spieler`s. You can see in your stack trace that the problem occurs in `Team.<init>`.

Answer (score 1):

`TeamSpieler` holds an array of twenty variables, each of which could point to a `Spieler` object -- but none of them do. Instead, the variables are all `null`, which is what causes your exceptions. At the top of your `for` loop you need to add, e.g.,

```
TeamSpieler[i] = new Spieler();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array with 20 entries, it will be filled with 20 `null` entries. Before you can access a `Spieler`, you first have to create them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < TeamSpieler.size(); i++) {
    TeamSpieler[i] = new Spieler();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements of the array need to be **individually** initialized.

In your code:

```
 TeamSpieler = new Spieler[20];
```

Initializes array with `null` values.

```
TeamSpieler[i].Name = team.nextLine();
```

Accesses `Name` property of `null` object.